# Packing different sized circles into rectangle - d3.js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, d3.js, packing

I was trying to pack circles of **different sizes into a rectangular container**, not packing in circular container that `d3.js` bundled with, under `d3.layout.pack`.

here's the layout I want to achieve:

[image]

I've found [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.5620&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on this matter, but I am not a math guy to understand the article throughly and convert them into code…

Anyone can suggest where I should start to convert this into d3.js layout plugin, or if you have visualized bubbles similar to this layout, please suggest any direction you took to solve that.

Thank you.

Comment: You're not aiming for optimality, are you? [This site](http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/cirinsqu/) suggests that finding optimal solutions, i.e. solutions that minimize the rectangle size, is likely to be tricky, even when restricted to the square case.

Comment: Thanks for the link! But what I want was to pack different-sized circles, not circles with same radius...

Comment: What I'm saying is that packing same sized circles into a square is difficult, and packing different sized circles into a rectangle is at least as difficult. You'll have to expect suboptimal situations, where a packing is possible but your algorithm won't find it.

Comment: @MvG Yeah, right. This seems a bit too difficult than I initially expected...

Comment: Did you ever get a solution (I saw your oDesk job post)? I'm want to use the same layout.

Comment: @cerberos As MvG noted last year, getting an *optimal* solution (to pack the circles into the smallest possible rectangle) is tricky; even the math-heavy paper linked to in the original post uses a "greedy" (i.e., imperfect) algorithm.  Getting an okay pack, however, should be feasible.  [This program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20917987/3128209) is similar, but constrains the horizontal position of the circles.  If I have time, I'll give it a go sometime this week, but in the meantime any one else is welcome to use that as a starting point!

Comment: So you have a number of circles of various known sizes, and you want to pack them into a rectangle of minimum area?  Or minimum max(width, height)?  Or do you have a rectangle of known, fixed size and you want to fill it with as many circles of various known sizes as possible?  Or what?

Comment: The rectangle is a known fixed size. An optimal solution is not necessary, any pack that reasonably uses the space is what I'm hoping for.

Comment: I was working from the assumption that the rectangle is fixed, and the relative sizes of the circles are fixed, but the scale used for sizing the circles relative to the rectangle is adjustable, and that you want to make the circles as large as possible to pack the rectangle as tightly as possible.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that while the proportions of the circles are fixed (because they map to some data), their scale is not? So the problem isn't fitting fixed-size circles into a fixed-size rectangle, but fitting circles in a known proportion into a rectangle of the correct aspect ratio, then scaling appropriately?

Comment: This could be useful: http://brainvise.com/2012/10/19/circle-packing/ made a fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/GVsrN/ - It's not considering the bounds though

Comment: @nrabinowitz just saw your question. Correct, rectangle is fixed size, circles map to data so proportions are fixed but actual size isn't.

Answer (score 33):

Here is a go at the implementation of your algorithm.

I tweaked it quite a bit, but I think it does basically the same thing.

#### Bounding circles

I used a trick to make the computation more regular.

Instead of segments defining the bounding box, I used circles with "infinite" radii, that can be considered a good approximation of lines:

[image: bounding circles]

The picture shows what the 4 bounding circles look like when the radius is decreased. They are computed to pass through the corners of the bounding box and converge toward the actual sides when the radius grows.

The "corner" circles (as the algorithm calls them) are all computed as tangents to a pair of circles, thus eliminating the special circle+segment or segment+segment cases.

This also simplifies the start condition greatly.
The algorithm simply starts with the four bounding circles and adds one circle at a time, using the greedy heuristic lambda parameter to pick the "best" location.

#### Best fit strategy

The original algorithm does not produce the smallest rectangle to hold all the circles
(it simply tries to fit a bunch of circles into a given rectangle).

I have added a simple dichotomic search on top of it to guess the minimal surface (which yields the smallest bounding rectangle for a given aspect ratio).

#### The code

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDzVE/)

```
var Packer = function (circles, ratio)
{
    this.circles = circles;
    this.ratio   = ratio || 1;
    this.list = this.solve();
}

Packer.prototype = {
    // try to fit all circles into a rectangle of a given surface
    compute: function (surface)
    {
        // check if a circle is inside our rectangle
        function in_rect (radius, center)
        {
            if (center.x - radius < - w/2) return false;
            if (center.x + radius >   w/2) return false;
            if (center.y - radius < - h/2) return false;
            if (center.y + radius >   h/2) return false;
            return true;
        }

        // approximate a segment with an "infinite" radius circle
        function bounding_circle (x0, y0, x1, y1)
        {
            var xm = Math.abs ((x1-x0)*w);
            var ym = Math.abs ((y1-y0)*h);
            var m = xm > ym ? xm : ym;
            var theta = Math.asin(m/4/bounding_r);
            var r = bounding_r * Math.cos (theta);
            return new Circle (bounding_r, 
                new Point (r*(y0-y1)/2+(x0+x1)*w/4, 
                           r*(x1-x0)/2+(y0+y1)*h/4));
        }

        // return the corner placements for two circles
        function corner (radius, c1, c2)
        {
            var u = c1.c.vect(c2.c); // c1 to c2 vector
            var A = u.norm();
            if (A == 0) return [] // same centers
            u = u.mult(1/A); // c1 to c2 unary vector
            // compute c1 and c2 intersection coordinates in (u,v) base
            var B = c1.r+radius;
            var C = c2.r+radius;
            if (A > (B + C)) return []; // too far apart
            var x = (A + (B*B-C*C)/A)/2;
            var y = Math.sqrt (B*B - x*x);
            var base = c1.c.add (u.mult(x));

            var res = [];
            var p1 = new Point (base.x -u.y * y, base.y + u.x * y);
            var p2 = new Point (base.x +u.y * y, base.y - u.x * y);
            if (in_rect(radius, p1)) res.push(new Circle (radius, p1));
            if (in_rect(radius, p2)) res.push(new Circle (radius, p2));
            return res;
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // deduce starting dimensions from surface
        var bounding_r = Math.sqrt(surface) * 100; // "infinite" radius
        var w = this.w = Math.sqrt (surface * this.ratio);
        var h = this.h = this.w/this.ratio;

        // place our bounding circles
        var placed=[
            bounding_circle ( 1,  1,  1, -1),
            bounding_circle ( 1, -1, -1, -1),
            bounding_circle (-1, -1, -1,  1),
            bounding_circle (-1,  1,  1,  1)];

        // Initialize our rectangles list
        var unplaced = this.circles.slice(0); // clones the array
        while (unplaced.length > 0)
        {
            // compute all possible placements of the unplaced circles
            var lambda = {};
            var circle = {};
            for (var i = 0 ; i != unplaced.length ; i++)
            {
                var lambda_min = 1e10;
                lambda[i] = -1e10;
                // match current circle against all possible pairs of placed circles
                for (var j = 0   ; j < placed.length ; j++)
                for (var k = j+1 ; k < placed.length ; k++)
                {
                    // find corner placement
                    var corners = corner (unplaced[i], placed[j], placed[k]);

                    // check each placement
                    for (var c = 0 ; c != corners.length ; c++)
                    {
                        // check for overlap and compute min distance
                        var d_min = 1e10;
                        for (var l = 0 ; l != placed.length ; l++)
                        {
                            // skip the two circles used for the placement
                            if (l==j || l==k) continue;

                            // compute distance from current circle
                            var d = placed[l].distance (corners[c]);
                            if (d < 0) break; // circles overlap

                            if (d < d_min) d_min = d;
                        }
                        if (l == placed.length) // no overlap
                        {
                            if (d_min < lambda_min)
                            {
                                lambda_min = d_min;
                                lambda[i] = 1- d_min/unplaced[i];
                                circle[i] = corners[c];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // select the circle with maximal gain
            var lambda_max = -1e10;
            var i_max = -1;
            for (var i = 0 ; i != unplaced.length ; i++)
            {
                if (lambda[i] > lambda_max)
                {
                    lambda_max = lambda[i];
                    i_max = i;
                }
            }

            // failure if no circle fits
            if (i_max == -1) break;

            // place the selected circle
            unplaced.splice(i_max,1);
            placed.push (circle[i_max]);
        }

        // return all placed circles except the four bounding circles
        this.tmp_bounds = placed.splice (0, 4);
        return placed;
    },

    // find the smallest rectangle to fit all circles
    solve: function ()
    {
        // compute total surface of the circles
        var surface = 0;
        for (var i = 0 ; i != this.circles.length ; i++)
        {
            surface += Math.PI * Math.pow(this.circles[i],2);
        }

        // set a suitable precision
        var limit = surface/1000;

        var step = surface/2;
        var res = [];
        while (step > limit)
        {
            var placement = this.compute.call (this, surface);
console.log ("placed",placement.length,"out of",this.circles.length,"for surface", surface);
            if (placement.length != this.circles.length)
            {
                surface += step;
            }
            else
            {
                res = placement;
                this.bounds = this.tmp_bounds;
                surface -= step;
            }
            step /= 2;
        }
        return res; 
    }
};
```

#### Performance

The code is not optimized, to favor readability (or so I hope :)).

The computation time rises pretty steeply.
You can safely place about 20 circles, but anything above 100 will make your browser crawl.

For some reason, it is way faster on FireFox than on IE11.

#### Packing efficiency

The algorithm works quite poorly on identically-sized circles (it cannot find the famous honeycomb pattern for 20 circles in a square), but pretty well on a wide distribution of random radii.

#### Aesthetics

The result is pretty ungainly for identical-sized circles.
There is no attempt to bunch the circles together, so if two possibilities are deemed equivalent by the algorithm, one is just picked at random.

I suspect the lambda parameter could be refined a bit to allow for a more aesthetic choice in case of equal values.

#### Possible evolutions

With the "infinite radii" trick, it becomes possible to define an arbitrary bounding polygon.

If you provide a function to check if a circle fits into the said polygon, there is no reason the algorithm should not produce a result.

Whether this result would be efficient is another question :).

Comment: Wow, this is the bomb. Are you familiar with d3? Would you be able to wrap this into a d3 layout. I already awarded the bounty as time was running out, I wasn't expecting any more answers so late on. I'll do another bounty next week and award it to you. Thanks for taking the time look at this.

Comment: Never used d3, but this looks like a good time to start :). I might run out of time to play with this little funny toy, but I'll have a look.

Comment: Looks great.  And I like the fact that the bounding box is described just as the intersection of other shapes, so it's extensible.

Comment: Great solution, but with different width and height, it still always makes bubbles fit within a square rectangle. What should change to align with the original requirements?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The basic algorithm simply fits the circles in a fixed-size box. A second algorithm uses a dichotomic search to optimize the size of that box so that there is the least amout of space lost. You control the shape of that box by defining a diagonal ratio (like for TVs or computer screens). What else do you need? Theoretically you could define an arbitrary convex polygonal shape for the container, but I never tried it. It would require some changes to the code.

Answer (score 26):

A completely different approach...

As I mentioned in a comment, a [d3 cluster-force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658) could be adapted into a heuristic method for fitting the circles into the box, by progressively changing the scale until you have a tight fit.

Results so far are not perfect, so I present a few versions:

Option 1, squeezes in the box to the space occupied by the circles *before* adjusting for circle overlap.  The result is very tightly packed, but with slight overlap between circles that get caught between the walls of the box and each other, unable to move without a conflict:
https://jsfiddle.net/LeGfW/2/

[image: Circle Packing results, option 1]

Option 2, squeezes in the box *after* separating overlapped circles.  This avoids overlap, but the packing isn't optimum since we don't ever push the circles into each other to force them to spread out to fill the long dimension of the rectangle:
https://jsfiddle.net/LeGfW/3/

[image: Circle packing results, option 2]

Option 3, the happy medium, again squeezes in after adjusting for overlap, but the squeeze factor is based on average out the room in width and height dimensions, instead of the minimum room, so it keeps squeezing until both width and height are filled:
https://jsfiddle.net/LeGfW/5/

[image: Circle packing results, option 3]

Key code consists of the `updateBubbles` method called by the force tick,
and the `collide` method which is called in the first line of `updateBubbles`.  This is the "option 3" version:

```
// Create a function for this tick round,
// with a new quadtree to detect collisions 
// between a given data element and all
// others in the layout, or the walls of the box.

//keep track of max and min positions from the quadtree
var bubbleExtent;
function collide(alpha) {
  var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree(data);
  var maxRadius = Math.sqrt(dataMax);
  var scaledPadding = padding/scaleFactor;
  var boxWidth = width/scaleFactor;
  var boxHeight = height/scaleFactor;

    //re-set max/min values to min=+infinity, max=-infinity:
  bubbleExtent = [[Infinity, Infinity],[-Infinity, -Infinity]];

  return function(d) {

      //check if it is pushing out of box:
    var r = Math.sqrt(d.size) + scaledPadding,
        nx1 = d.x - r,
        nx2 = d.x + r,
        ny1 = d.y - r,
        ny2 = d.y + r;

      if (nx1 < 0) {
           d.x = r;
      }
      if (nx2 > boxWidth) {
           d.x = boxWidth - r;
      }
      if (ny1 < 0) {
           d.y = r;
      }
      if (ny2 > boxHeight) {
           d.y = boxHeight - r;
      }


    //check for collisions
    r = r + maxRadius, 
        //radius to center of any possible conflicting nodes
        nx1 = d.x - r,
        nx2 = d.x + r,
        ny1 = d.y - r,
        ny2 = d.y + r;

    quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
      if (quad.point && (quad.point !== d)) {
        var x = d.x - quad.point.x,
            y = d.y - quad.point.y,
            l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
            r = Math.sqrt(d.size) + Math.sqrt(quad.point.size)
                    + scaledPadding;
        if (l < r) {
          l = (l - r) / l * alpha;
          d.x -= x *= l;
          d.y -= y *= l;
          quad.point.x += x;
          quad.point.y += y;
        }
      }
      return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    });

    //update max and min
    r = r-maxRadius; //return to radius for just this node
    bubbleExtent[0][0] = Math.min(bubbleExtent[0][0], 
                                  d.x - r);
    bubbleExtent[0][1] = Math.min(bubbleExtent[0][1], 
                                  d.y - r);
    bubbleExtent[1][0] = Math.max(bubbleExtent[1][0], 
                                  d.x + r);
    bubbleExtent[1][1] = Math.max(bubbleExtent[1][1], 
                                  d.y + r);

  };
}  

function updateBubbles() {

    bubbles
        .each( collide(0.5) ); //check for collisions   

    //update the scale to squeeze in the box 
    //to match the current extent of the bubbles
    var bubbleWidth = bubbleExtent[1][0] - bubbleExtent[0][0];
    var bubbleHeight = bubbleExtent[1][1] - bubbleExtent[0][1];

    scaleFactor = (height/bubbleHeight +
                           width/bubbleWidth)/2; //average
    /*
    console.log("Box dimensions:", [height, width]);
    console.log("Bubble dimensions:", [bubbleHeight, bubbleWidth]);
    console.log("ScaledBubble:", [scaleFactor*bubbleHeight,
                                 scaleFactor*bubbleWidth]);
    //*/

    rScale
        .range([0,  Math.sqrt(dataMax)*scaleFactor]);

    //shift the bubble cluster to the top left of the box
    bubbles
        .each( function(d){
            d.x -= bubbleExtent[0][0];
            d.y -= bubbleExtent[0][1];
        });

    //update positions and size according to current scale:
    bubbles
        .attr("r", function(d){return rScale(d.size);} )
        .attr("cx", function(d){return scaleFactor*d.x;})
        .attr("cy", function(d){return scaleFactor*d.y;})
}
```

Comment: Good use of pictures!

Comment: Option 3 is the best that I've seen so far. Although unfortunately it's not quite what I'm looking for since can't be converted to a d3 layout because it starts with a d3.layout.pack() and uses a force layout with collision handling in order to 'find' the final positions. Thanks for taking the time, I've awarded you the bounty so that it doesn't go to waste.

Comment: Yes, the bouncing around of force layout can be distracting for some uses.

Comment: Slightly better results if I turn off the elevated gravity parameter: http://fiddle.jshell.net/LeGfW/6/.  About equal results if you skip the initial circle pack, and just position the circles in a grid: http://fiddle.jshell.net/LeGfW/7/

Comment: You don't need the bouncing - the animation is optional. Just don't render until the positions are final.

Comment: Layouting can be ended early by _seconds_ - without significant impact on the result in most cases - by checking `force.alpha()`'s value repeatedly (every ~100ms) and calling `force.stop()` as soon as an empiric threshold is reached. This is useful if relevant UI elements are added after initial packing.

Answer (score 5):

Well, this is far from optimal packing, but it's something that others can try to beat.

*Updated, but still not great*

https://jsfiddle.net/LF9Yp/6/

Key code, such as it is:

```
var points = [[]]; //positioned circles, by row
function assignNextPosition(d,index) {
    console.log("fitting circle ", index, d.size);
    var i, j, n;
    var radiusPlus = rScale(d.size) + padding;
    if (!points[0].length) { //this is first object
       d.x = d.y = radiusPlus; 
       points[0].push(d);
       points[0].width = points[0].height = 2*radiusPlus;
       points[0].base = 0;
       return;
    }
    i = 0; n = points.length - 1; 
    var tooTight, lastRow, left, rp2, hyp;
    while ((tooTight = (width - points[i].width < 2*radiusPlus)
            ||( points[i+1]? 
                points[i+1].base - points[i].base < 2*radiusPlus 
                : false) ) 
          &&(i < n) ) i++;
           //skim through rows to see if any can fit this circle

    if (!tooTight) { console.log("fit on row ", i);
        //one of the rows had room
        lastRow = points[i];
        j=lastRow.length;

        if (i == 0) {
          //top row, position tight to last circle and wall
            d.y = radiusPlus;
            rp2 = (rScale(lastRow[j-1].size) + padding);
            d.x = lastRow[j-1].x + Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow( (radiusPlus + rp2), 2)
                - Math.pow( (radiusPlus - rp2),2) );
        }
        else {
           //position tight to three closest circles/wall
           //(left, top left and top right)
            //or (left, top left and right wall)
           var left = lastRow[j-1];
           d.x = left.x + rScale(left.size) + padding + radiusPlus;
           var prevRow = points[i - 1];       
           j = prevRow.length;
           while ((j--) && (prevRow[j].x > d.x));
           j = Math.max(j,0);
           if (j + 1 < prevRow.length) {
               console.log("fit between", prevRow[j], prevRow[j+1]);
               d.y = prevRow[j].y 
               + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((radiusPlus + 
                           rScale(prevRow[j].size) +padding), 2) 
                           - Math.pow( (d.x - prevRow[j].x),2)
                       )||0);
              j++;
              d.y = Math.max(d.y, prevRow[j].y 
               + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((radiusPlus + 
                           rScale(prevRow[j].size) +padding), 2) 
                           - Math.pow( (d.x - prevRow[j].x),2)
                       )||0)  );
           }
           else { //tuck tight against wall
               console.log("fit between", prevRow[j], "wall");
            d.x = width - radiusPlus;
            rp2 = (rScale(prevRow[j].size) + padding);
            d.y = prevRow[j].y + (Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow( (radiusPlus + rp2), 2)
                - Math.pow( (d.x - prevRow[j].x),2) )||0);
            if (i > 1)
                d.y = Math.max(d.y, points[i-2].height + radiusPlus);
           }
        }

        lastRow.push(d); 
        lastRow.width = d.x + radiusPlus;
        lastRow.height = Math.max(lastRow.height, 
                                  d.y + radiusPlus);
        lastRow.base = Math.min(lastRow.base,
                                d.y - radiusPlus);

    } else { console.log("new row ", points.length)
        prevRow = points[points.length -1];
        j=prevRow.length;
        while(j--) {
            var testY = prevRow[j].y + rScale(prevRow[j].size) + padding
                  + radiusPlus;
            if (testY + radiusPlus < prevRow.height) {
                //tuck row in gap
                d.x = prevRow[j].x;
                d.y = testY;
            }
        }
        if (!d.x) {//start row at left
          d.x = radiusPlus;
          d.y = prevRow.height + radiusPlus;
        }
        var newRow = [d];
        newRow.width = d.x + radiusPlus;
        newRow.height = Math.max(d.y + radiusPlus, prevRow.height);
        newRow.base = d.y - radiusPlus;
        points.push(newRow); 
    } 
            if (!d.y) console.log("error",d);
    if (d.y + radiusPlus > height) {
      //change rScale by the ratio this exceeds the height
      var scaleFactor = height/(d.y + radiusPlus);
      rScale.range([0, rScale.range()[1]*scaleFactor]);

      //recalculate all positions
      points.forEach(function(row, j){
            row.forEach(function(d, i) {
               d.x = (d.x - i*2*padding)*scaleFactor + i*2*padding;
               d.y = (d.y - i*2*padding)*scaleFactor + i*2*padding;
            });
            row.width *= scaleFactor;
      });

    }

}
```

Comment: Ever since this question popped up with a bounty, I really wanted to give this a try. Not even started yet. But I really have to say, good try. Have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks @bits.  A lot of messing around for not a great solution.  I still think the key will be using a quadtree structure, but I couldn't figure out how to use it, hence the approach of packing in irregular rows.  But then there are just too many checks to keep track of!  After doing this, I thought of a way to use quadtree, but instead of storing the locations of circles, you store the locations and size of open space.  However, I don't think I'll have time this week to try it out...

Comment: Did you think of trying to implement the [research paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.99.5620&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which OP referenced?

Comment: Also someone can try leveraging [a physics engine](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html) to reduce so much complex programming.

Comment: I honestly hadn't looked at the paper too closely, but it's also based on keeping track of gaps rather than keeping track of occupied space. What it doesn't discuss is how to efficiently manage the data structure to do that.  But if you could get the quadtree to help keep track of gaps, then you'd want to use their algorithm for efficient packing.

Comment: On the "physics" approach, that's another direction to take entirely.  For d3, you could work from [something like this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658), which uses the force layout to cluster circles tightly together.  You'd have to add a bounding box of the correct aspect ratio, and then slowly squeeze the walls in (or conversely, grow every circle) until you can't pack them any tighter.

Comment: I took a look at the JSFiddle, and I have this question:  What does the final bubble sizing?  Does the Force layout (the optimizing your code comments say)?  Or does the pack layout's initial sizing stay as the final sizing?  I'm ultimately wondering if the bubble sizing is [proportionally] maximized to the rectangle... Thanks!

Comment: @cellepo: The final size is adjusted in my code by changing the `rScale` and `scaleFactor`  so that the packed size of the bubbles is scaled up to fill the entire rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

If your primary concern finding a *tight* packing of different-sized circles within a rectangle, then unfortunately you'll have to implement a new d3 layout. I don't know of a plugin that's already written that will do this.

However, if what you're looking for is *any* old packing into a rectangle, then you can use the the existing circle packing algorithm that d3 provides in `d3.layout.pack`. When you specify the bounds for this layout, you're specifying the dimensions of a rectangle. d3 then determines a circle that the bounding rectangle will circumscribe, and uses that circle to visualize the root of the hierarchical data. So what you can do is provide a "dummy" root node which you don't actually render, and have the real data that you want to visualize be the children of that node.

Code example below, and I also [put it up on bl.ocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org/4127259) so you can see it in action.

```
var w = 640,
    h = 480;

var data = {
  name : "root",
  children : [
    { name: '1', size: 100 }, { name: '2', size: 85 },
    { name: '3', size: 70 } , { name: '4', size: 55 },
    { name: '5', size: 40 } , { name: '6', size: 25 },
    { name: '7', size: 10 } ,
  ]
}

var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var nodes = d3.layout.pack()
  .value(function(d) { return d.size; })
  .size([w, h])
  .nodes(data);

// Get rid of root node
nodes.shift();

canvas.selectAll('circles')
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append('svg:circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr('fill', 'white')
    .attr('stroke', 'grey');
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. All this does is pack the circles into a parent circle that isn't shown. It doesn't take advantage of any of the extra space provided by the rectangle, to allow for the child circles to be scaled larger.

Comment: @HelpMeStackOverflowMyOnlyHope My answer pretty much states that.

Answer (score -1):

There's a much better way to do this -- using Mitchell's Best Fit algorithm.

This is the general pattern:

```
function drawCircles() { 
  var w = (parseInt(d3.select(".circles-div").style('width'), 10)) * 0.34,
    h = 350;

  d3.csv('dataset.csv', function(error, data) {

    var maxRadius = 8, // maximum radius of circle
      padding = 3, // padding between circles; also minimum radius
      margin = {top: maxRadius, right: maxRadius, bottom: maxRadius, left: maxRadius},
      width = w - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

     var color = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([50,10])
      .range(['#666','#efefef'])
      .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

    var logscale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0,8]);

    logscale.domain([0,500])

    var k = 1, // initial number of candidates to consider per circle
        m = 100, // initial number of circles to add per frame
        n = data.length, // remaining number of circles to add
        newCircle = bestCircleGenerator(maxRadius, padding);

    var svg = d3.select(".circles-div").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
      .append("g")
        .attr('class','bubbles')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.timer(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < m && --n >= 0; ++i) {

        var maxR = logscale(data[n]['Radius_value'])

        var circle = newCircle(k);

        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", circle[0])
            .attr("cy", circle[1])
            .attr("r", 0)
            .style('fill', color(data[n]['Color_value']))
          .transition()
            .attr("r", logscale(data[n]['Radius_value']));

        if (k < 500) k *= 1.01, m *= .998;
      }
      return !n;
    });

    function bestCircleGenerator(maxRadius, padding) {

      var quadtree = d3.geom.quadtree().extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])([]),
      searchRadius = maxRadius * 2,
      maxRadius2 = maxRadius * maxRadius;

      return function(k) {

        var bestX, bestY, bestDistance = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < k || bestDistance < padding; ++i) {
          var x = Math.random() * width,
              y = Math.random() * height,
              rx1 = x - searchRadius,
              rx2 = x + searchRadius,
              ry1 = y - searchRadius,
              ry2 = y + searchRadius,
              minDistance = maxRadius; // minimum distance for this candidate

          quadtree.visit(function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            if (p = quad.point) {
              var p,
                  dx = x - p[0],
                  dy = y - p[1],
                  d2 = dx * dx + dy * dy,
                  r2 = p[2] * p[2];
              if (d2 < r2) return minDistance = 0, true; // within a circle
              var d = Math.sqrt(d2) - p[2];
              if (d < minDistance) minDistance = d;
            }
            return !minDistance || x1 > rx2 || x2 < rx1 || y1 > ry2 || y2 < ry1; // or outside search radius
          });

          if (minDistance > bestDistance) bestX = x, bestY = y, bestDistance = minDistance;
        }

        var best = [bestX, bestY, bestDistance - padding];
        quadtree.add(best);
        return best;
      };
    }

    });

  }
```

[See for](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1893974) example with random data.

Comment: How is this algorithm possibly relates to packing predefined number of circles with predefined size into a rectangle??