# d3.js circle packing along a line

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I got a data set that where each sample has a size (0-1000) and a value (grade 1-5).  I want to visualise the data with circles of different sizes along a line (domain axis), much like:

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/05/25/sunday-review/corporate-taxes.html?_r=1&

(note that circles even with the same effective taxrate do not overlap)

Example data:

- sample 1: size 300  value 3.2
- sample 2: size 45 value 3.8
- sample 3: size 4400 value 4.0
- sample 5: size 233 value 0.2
- sample 6: size 4000 value 4.2

How can the data above be visualised using circles on a line (*size* decides diameter, *value* decides approximate position on the line) so that circles do not overlap?

I've been looking at D3's packing layout, but from what I can tell it doesn't support this out of the box.  Anyone got any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: If it's a straight line all you would need to do is sum up the diameters of the preceding circles to get the position for a new circle.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Could you elaborate a bit (I updated the question) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Oooh, this one was a puzzle...

If you look at the code for the NYTimes graphic, it uses pre-computed coordinates in the data file, so that's not much use.

However, there's an unused variable declaration at the top of the script that hints that the original version used [`d3.geom.quadtree`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quadtree-Geom) to lay out the circles.  The quadtree isn't actually a layout method; it is used to create a search tree of adjacent nodes, so that when you need to find a node in a given area you don't have to search through the whole set.  [Example here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4343214).

The quadtree can therefore be used to identify which of your datapoints might be overlapping each other on the x-axis.  Then you have to figure out how much you need to offset them in order to avoid that overlap.  The variable radii complicate both functions...

I've got a test case implemented here:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/6cW9u/5/

The packing algorithm isn't perfect:  I always add new circles to the outside of existing circles, without testing whether they could possibly fit closer in, so sometimes you get significant extra whitespace when it is just the far edges of circles bumping into each other.  (Run it a few times to get an idea of the possibilities -- note that I've got x-variables distributed as random normal and r-variables distributed as random uniform.)  I also got a stack overflow on the recursive methods during one iteration with N=100 -- the random distribution clearly wasn't distributed well enough for the quadtree optimization.

But it's got the basic functionality.  Leave a comment here if you can't follow the logic of my code comments.

--ABR

## Update

New fiddle here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6cW9u/8/

After a lot of re-arranging, I got the packing algorithm to search for gaps between existing bubbles.  I've got the sort order switched (so that biggest circles get added first) to show off how little circles can get added in the gaps -- although as I mention in the code comments, this reduces the efficiency of the quadtree search.

Also added various decoration and transition so you can clearly see how the circles are being positioned, and set the r-scale to be square root, so the area (not radius) is proportional to the value in the data (which is more realistic, and what the O.P. asked for).

Comment: Brilliant! I want also to add that the original visualization actually doesn't accurately reflect data on horizontal axis - if you carefully examine data that show in tooltips, you'll see it. So, the positions are tweaked, manually or not, and we see just hardcoded result.

Comment: I am running the fiddle with N=125, and layouts are quite satisfactory, even beautiful, however, it looks there is a bug (maybe the same that you mentioned) that kicks in from time to time, and places almost all circles right on the axis...

Comment: Yep, that's what happens when the stack overflows -- you don't get a valid y offset.  It seems to be related to x values outside the domain I set in the quadtree's extent.  So the logical thing to do would be to make sure you set the quadtree extent based on the actual data range.  *(I cheated in my updated fiddle and just used a value large enough that the probability that my random normal would be outside it was very small.)*

Comment: @AmeliaBR I'm trying to update your code to v4 but I'm running into an issue with the quadroot. the root not is always undefined.

Comment: @Mike Looking over the [list of changes](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#quadtrees-d3-quadtree), maybe you need to change the initial `quadroot = quadtree()` assignment to `quadroot = `quadtree().root`? Or perhaps you need to add the first data item before you get get a valid root node? I'm afraid I haven't played around with quadtrees and D3v4 yet.

Answer (score 3):

D3's packing layout is not the answer here. It places circles in a spiral fashion around the existing group. Here's me reverse-engineering the algorithm behind packing layout:

[image]

I would suggest a [force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout)-based approach. That way, you can give your nodes force towards a gravitational center, and then let gravity do its thing.

Force layouts (e.g. [Clustered Force Layout I](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1747543)) are usually animations, so you'll want to apply a [static force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139).

I've wrapped up this approach [in an example block](http://bl.ocks.org/ericandrewlewis/dc79d22c74b8046a5512), which looks like this:

[image: circles on a line in a static force layout]