# How to use a D3 packing layout or force layout across a horizontal axis?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to figure out how Mike Bostock did this force/pack layout across a horizontal axis:
http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/05/25/sunday-review/corporate-taxes.html?_r=1&

I know that you can do multiple centers and have the nodes repel one another. I also understand that there are sorting options as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't actually using the pack layout or force layout -- it's a combination of quadtree for collision detection and voronoi.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks Lars. Are you sure that this is the case? It seems odd for Mike Bostock to not use d3 to generate this visualization. It seems that quadtree isn't in d3 either.

Comment: It's in D3. Have a look at the source of the page.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff here's a link to the JS. It looks like he uses both layout.force and layout.pack: http://graphics8.nytimes.com/newsgraphics/2013/05/13/corporate-taxes/ee84b0191a75f5c652087293ab0efd4710e21f94/lib.js

Comment: That's the included library. The actual vis is drawn in the source of the main page.

Comment: I discuss that exact viz and provide an example of doing something similar in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20917987/3128209  In the NY Times example, the positions have all been pre-calculated and stored in the dataset.