# Force chart d3.js inside a triangle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, polygon, force-layout

I'm studying d3.js force chart and I have a question. **Is it possible to make a force chart inside a triangle with some coordinates?**

Here is my code:

```
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
//margin
var marginLeft = 10;
var marginTop = 10;
var marginRight = 10;
var marginBottom = 10;
var margin = { left: marginLeft , top: marginTop, right: marginRight, bottom: marginBottom};

//size of canvas
var innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
var innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var radius = 10;

var svg = d3.select(".forcechart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width) 
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("background", "#eee");

var tr = svg.append("polygon")       // attach a polygon
    .style("stroke", "black")  // colour the line
    .style("fill", "none")     // remove any fill colour
    .attr("points", "250,0, 12,173,  250,250");  // x,y points 

var group = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform",  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var graph = {
    "nodes": [  { "x": 0, "y": 0 },
                { "x": 100,  "y":  100 },
                { "x": 500, "y": 500 },
                     { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
                   { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
                  { "x": 100,  "y":  100 },
                { "x": 500, "y": 500 },
                     { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
                   { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
                  { "x": 100,  "y":  100 },
                { "x": 500, "y": 500 },
                     { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
                   { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
                  { "x": 100,  "y":  100 },
                { "x": 500, "y": 500 },
                     { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
                   { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
                  { "x": 100,  "y":  100 },
                { "x": 500, "y": 500 },
                     { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
                   { "x": 300, "y": 0 },
            ],
    "links": []
    };


var nodes = graph.nodes,
    links = graph.links;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([innerWidth, innerHeight])
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links);

force.linkDistance(100);
force.charge(-200);

var link = group.selectAll('.link')
    .data(links)
    .enter().append('line')
    .attr('class', 'link');

var node = group.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'node');

force.on('tick', function() {
    node.attr('r', radius)
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });

    link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });

});


force.start();
```

Full code is here: http://codepen.io/Balzzac/pen/vGWXdQ. Now it is a force chart inside "group", I need to make it is inside triangle "tr" so no one node is outside of boundaries of my triangle.

Thanks for help!

PS Sorry for my English =)

Comment: This probably involves some computer graphics algorithms. without a solid background in algorithms it would be hard to implement. would be nice if someone can invest some time and code a solution for this.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573178/d3-force-directed-layout-with-bounding-box

Comment: To fix the `cx` and `cy`, the math is here: https://bl.ocks.org/milkbread/11000965

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's really two parts to this question.  First, you need your force layout to converge on a different foci then the default [width/2, height/2](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#size).  This new foci should be the centroid of the triangle.  Luckily `d3` has [a helper method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Polygon-Geom#centroid) to compute this for polygons.  Second, now that we are converging on the centroid of the triangle, how do we bound our nodes inside that triangle.  The method I use below calculates the intersections between lines drawn from the centroid to the node and the line of the edge of the triangle (intersection calculation from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)).  No intersections  on all 3 edges means the circle is in the triangle, and an intersection on any edge means we need to bring the circle onto that edge.

**UPDATE** -- generalized the code a bit and converted it to a [block here](http://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/39a028da44db9e8daf14578cb354b5cb) to work with N sided polygons.

Let's get to the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var width = 500,
        height = 500,
        radius = 10;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .style("background", "#eee");

    // our polygon
    var trianglePoints = [
      [250, 0],
      [12, 173],
      [250, 250]
    ];

    var tr = svg.append("polygon") // attach a polygon
      .style("stroke", "black") // colour the line
      .style("fill", "none") // remove any fill colour
      .attr("points", trianglePoints.join(" ")); // x,y points 

    var group = svg.append("g");

    var nodes = d3.range(20).map(function(d){ return {} }),
      links = [],
      cent = d3.geom.polygon(trianglePoints).centroid();

    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([width, height])
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links);

    force.linkDistance(100);
    force.charge(-200);

    var link = group.selectAll('.link')
      .data(links)
      .enter().append('line')
      .attr('class', 'link');

    var node = group.selectAll('.node')
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .call(force.drag); //<-- make them draggable to test

    force.on('tick', function(e) {

      node.attr('r', radius)
        .attr('transform', function(d) {

          // change focus to the center of the triangle
          var x = (d.x - (width / 2 - cent[0])),
            y = (d.y - (height / 2 - cent[1]));

          // test intersections on all 3 edges
          var i = 
            getLineIntersection(trianglePoints[0][0], trianglePoints[0][1],
              trianglePoints[1][0], trianglePoints[1][1], cent[0], cent[1], x, y) ||
            getLineIntersection(trianglePoints[1][0], trianglePoints[1][1],
              trianglePoints[2][0], trianglePoints[2][1], cent[0], cent[1], x, y) ||
            getLineIntersection(trianglePoints[0][0], trianglePoints[0][1],
                trianglePoints[2][0], trianglePoints[2][1], cent[0], cent[1], x, y) ||
            false;
          
          // set it to intersection
          if (i){
            x = i.x;
            y = i.y;
          }

          return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";

        });

      link.attr('x1', function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr('y1', function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr('x2', function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr('y2', function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

    });

    // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect
    function getLineIntersection(p0_x, p0_y, p1_x, p1_y, p2_x, p2_y, p3_x, p3_y) {
      var s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
      s1_x = p1_x - p0_x;
      s1_y = p1_y - p0_y;
      s2_x = p3_x - p2_x;
      s2_y = p3_y - p2_y;
      var s, t;
      s = (-s1_y * (p0_x - p2_x) + s1_x * (p0_y - p2_y)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
      t = (s2_x * (p0_y - p2_y) - s2_y * (p0_x - p2_x)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);

      if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t <= 1) {
        var intX = p0_x + (t * s1_x);
        var intY = p0_y + (t * s1_y);
        return {
          x: intX,
          y: intY
        };
      }
      return false;
    }

    force.start();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```