# Algorithm to distribute N points in a rectangle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, cover

Given a rectangle of width W and height H distribute n points such that at every point has another one at distance at most (d_r) and no other point at distance at least (d_c). We can suppose d_r < d_c. My first idea has been to distribute points uniformly in the positions (0,0), (0, d_c), (d_c, 0). But while this solution covers the requirements of the problem I don't think it will always find the solutions, since most subtle coverings may be needed. Is there any specific algorithm for a problem like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Packing different sized circles into rectangle - d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339615/packing-different-sized-circles-into-rectangle-d3-js)

Comment: You should specify if you are trying to distribute points inside of the rectangle or in the boundary of the rectangle.