# Using D3.js to tightly pack circles into a rectangle to display using Chart.js

Tags: d3.js, chart.js, circle-pack

I am trying to create a single level circle packing (into a rectangle) solution for ChartJS aiming for the following

- tightly packed, making maximum use of the available space
- automatically scale radii to ensure all circles fit within the confines without clipping or overlapping (ideally able to define a minimum gap between them as well to allow for hover animations etc)
- have an affinity towards an arbitrary point (default the center of the rectangle)

currently I have put together the following code from my [answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76911169/1569675), but as it uses the older D3.js functionality it's probably not a good long term solution.

Is there a way to enhance this solution to use `forceSimulation` to enhance the fidelity of the data that I can then feed to Chart.JS? From initial experiments with that I'm happy that there will be a short period of time where the circles 'settle' but I've been struggling with both the automatic scaling (that the older `layout.pack` gave me) and knowing when the layout is 'good enough' to display.

Chart.JS is required for our particular use-case, and while D3.js seems like it can be leveraged for this I'm open to other solutions which accomplish the same goal (eg [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/GVsrN/) which is fast but sadly doesn't take into account the clipping at the edges or apply any scaling to avoid overlap)

```js
var w = document.getElementById("c").offsetWidth,
  h = document.getElementById("c").offsetHeight;

// build random set of circles for the d3 packing
var data = {
  "name": "root",
  "children": []
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  data["children"].push({
    "name": i,
    "size": Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1)
  })
}

// use D3 to pack into the canvas size, with a little bit of padding
var nodes = d3.layout.pack()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.size;
  })
  .size([w, h])
  .padding(4)
  .nodes(data);

// Get rid of root node
nodes.shift();

// take the packed nodes data, and push to format ChartJS expects for bubbles
nodedata = [];
for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  node = nodes[i]
  nodedata.push({
    "x": node.x,
    "y": node.y,
    "r": node.r
  })
}

// create a bubble chart with no labels, border lines etc
var bubbleChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("cc"), {
  type: 'bubble',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: nodedata,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(212,121,212,1)"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },
        grid: {
          display: false
        },
        border: {
          display: false
        }
      },
      y: {
        display: false,
        ticks: {
          display: false,
        },
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
        border: {
          display: false
        }
      }
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#c {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 380px;
  height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<div id="c"><canvas id="cc"></canvas></div>
```